# Converting coordinates of a picture in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I use python's matplotlib to plot some data using imshow(). At the same time I plot some other things along with it in other subplots. The thing is that one pixel in my picture is equivalent to 20000 units in other subplots, but I want to use sharex, so that zooming into one plot would cause zooming in all others. The most obvious idea I had is to somehow convert coordinates in the image, so that coordinates of different subplots were "compatible"(=identical) with each other. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The easiest would be to provide the `extent` to `imshow`.

Comment: Thank you, @RutgerKassies, it solved my problem! If you could just post it as an answer, I would accept it.